# setInterval inside FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, setinterval

This is what I tried to do

```
for ( i=1; i<=1000; i+=100) {
 setInterval(someFunction, i);
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when page loads the box will appear and its shadow will twinkle slow and then fast and will stop at when i=1000.
I am newbie and so far, I did [this](http://jsbin.com/eruyic/2).

Comment: Too bad. If you tell us what does not work and which error you get, we might be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work out"? We _cannot_ help if you don't give enough detail in your question - you need to say why it didn't work; what behaviour you _got_ and what behaviour you _want_.

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish? How didn't it work?

Comment: Is it possible or not? That's all I need. If yes, give me example please!

Comment: @FoxKllD: Yes.  It's possible.  As for how, well, that depends on *what you were trying to do in the first place*.  What you have there almost certainly won't do what you want, but we need input on what you want it to do.

Comment: I guess this might freeze/crash some browsers. What's your desired result? Do you want to pass **i** as argument to **someFunction**? Or maybe you are looking for setTimeout() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible or not?**

Yes. Assuming `someFunction` is either a reference to a function or a string containing JavaScript code your for loop will "work" as is, where by "work" I mean "not give syntax errors but almost certainly not achieve what I imagine you really want to do".

The [`setInterval()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) calls the function you pass it *repeatedly*, with a fixed (subject to browser quirks) delay between each call. It keeps calling the function for as long as the page is open or until you use `clearInterval()` to cancel it.

So by calling `setInterval()` in a loop you are setting up (in your case) ten independent intervals all of which call your function repeatedly. The first calls `someFunction` at a 0ms interval, which is smaller than the browser will actually use so will be rounded up to more like 4ms. The second interval will call `someFunction` at a 100ms interval. The third calls the function at a 200ms interval. And so on. After your loop finishes your function will be repeatedly called more times per second than I can be bothered to calculate.

It seems likely that what you really wanted to do is call `someFunction()` exactly 10 times with a 100ms delay between each call. If that is the case you could instead use the [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) within your loop, because (each use of) `setTimeout()` will call your function exactly once after the specified delay.

Comment: I am newbie, could you tell me what is `setTimeOut()`

Comment: I already told you. As I said at the end of my answer, `setTimeout()` will "call your function exactly once after the specified delay", as compared to `setInterval()`, which will call your function repeatedly. Look at the MDN pages I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put set interval in a loop for run it more than once.

try reading through this tutorial on [javascript.info](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: And that happens to be one of the bad examples, too.  Passing a string of JS code to `setInterval` is so 1990s.  I think even then it was bad; we just didn't know any better.  :P

Comment: @cHao - If you go back far enough passing a string was the only option.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that w3schools was such a bad resource.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Since when? Javascript have always supported closures from the beginning. There was never ever a need to pass strings.

Comment: @slebetman - According to MDN, `setTimeout()` was "Introduced with JavaScript 1.0, Netscape 2.0. _Passing a Function object reference was introduced with JavaScript 1.2_, Netscape 4.0; supported by the MSHTML DOM since version 5.0" (my emphasis). I assumed that `setInterval()` was the same.